# Can I save the numbers from file more than array size?

Tags: java, arrays

The question is Assume that the array can store a maximum of 5 numbers. Your method will need to ensure that a maximum of 5 numbers are read from the file even if there are more than 5 values in the file. You cannot assume that there will always be 5 values in the file. The method should no longer display the values to the screen.
but when I save my values over 5 number I get wrong message is Index 5 out of bounds for length 5.

```
System.out.println("Input the file name");
names = ff.nextLine();

try {
    File f = new File(names);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
            
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) { // get how many number we have
        inputFile.nextInt();     
        line++;             
    }
    
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(f); // scanner all the number and save to array
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++) {
        store[i] = inputFile2.nextInt();
    }

    inputFile.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("The file is not exit"); // if cannot find the file
}
```

the file values is 1-10, how can I only use array to save 5 values in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {  // get how many number we have
    inputFile.nextInt();     
    line=line+1;                
}
```

Alright so this looks like you're counting the line numbers (which you don't need to do, but I see your approach). In your example you said there were 10 lines, so `line` is equal to 10. But then you do this:

```java
for(int i=0;i<line;i++) {
    store[i]=inputFile2.nextInt();
}
```

This code is putting each int in the next position of the array **10 times**, since `line` is 10. You didn't show how you initialized your array but I'm guessing that it has a length of 5. That means, when `i` = 5 in your for loop, there is no 5th position to put anything into your array at, so you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. What you want to do instead is this:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(line, stores.length); i++) {
    store[i]=inputFile2.nextInt();
}
```

This code instead will stop the loop at whatever is smaller, the length of the array or the number of lines in the file. In this case, `stores.length` would be 5, so you'd fill the array 5 times from 0 to 4. If in another scenario you had an array of length 15 instead (and `line` is still 10), `Math.min(line, stores.length)` would return the value that `line` holds, which is 10, so it would only fill up to position 10 in the array, and the rest will be 0s (assuming it is an `int[]`).

Comment: Thanks so much answer me this question, I think I did not understand the question, but I was use reassigning array references to slove this question.

Comment: Anytime! If this answer helped you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to add a maximum of 5 values to an array even if the referenced array exceeds 5. I would suggest using a while loop in place of the for-loop so that you don't have to iterate over the entire array try using the code below

```
var loop = 0;
while(loop < 5 && loop < line)
{
    store[loop] = inputFile2.nextInt();
    loop++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you guys answer me this question, but I think I figure out by myself, I use reassigning array references

```
System.out.println("Input the file name");
            names = ff.nextLine();
        try {
            File f = new File(names);
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
            
            while (inputFile.hasNext()) {  // get how many number we have
                inputFile.nextInt();     
                line=line+1;                
              }
            store = new int[line];   // get new size for the array
            Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(f);  // scanner all the number and save to array
            for(int i=0;i<line;i++) {
                store[i]=inputFile2.nextInt();
            }
            
            inputFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The file is not exit");     // if cannot find the file
        }
```

I add "store = new int[line];" this code to reassigning array references, so when I first scanner the file I can get how many numbers I have, so that I can definition new size for my array, I think it is works abd I appreciate you guys can help me, if this code have some issue, please tell me